# labelling subplots automatically

Tags: matlab

I have 4 subplots in a figure and want to label them a, b, c, and d.  I would like for the letters to be placed automatically in the top left hand corner of each subplot.  I know that I can add text manually, but is there a more efficent way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put something along these lines into a script:

```
subplot(2,2,1)
text(0.02,0.98,'a','Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top')
subplot(2,2,2)
text(0.02,0.98,'b','Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top')
subplot(2,2,3)
text(0.02,0.98,'c','Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top')
subplot(2,2,4)
text(0.02,0.98,'d','Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top')
```

Note that I'm assuming your subplots are arranged in a 2x2 grid and that they are all 2D plots.  If these assumptions do not hold, modify the first two arguments of subplot and/or add a z coordinate to text.

Answer (score 2):

You can as well specify the number of lines you want in the subplot and increment the letters using the function char:

```
% data:
myTriangle=(triang(100));
amplitudeFactor=[1 0.7 0.6  0.4 0.2];

% Plot, specifying number of lines in subplot:
nLine=2;
nPlot=length(amplitudeFactor);
for ind=1:nPlot
    subplot(nLine, ceil(nPlot/nLine),ind)
    plot(myTriangle*amplitudeFactor(ind))
    set(gca,'YLim',[0 1])
    text(0.02,0.98,char('a' + ind - 1),'Units', 'Normalized', 'VerticalAlignment', 'Top')
end
```